# Ошибка сборки "undefined reference" в mysqlconnector (mysqlcppconn)

Tags: c++, mysqlconnector

ОС: Windows

Для работы с БД выбрал MySQL Connector C++.
Подключил библиотеку mysqlcppconn-9-vs14 к проекту, но при сборке выдает ошибку:

```
debug/main.o: In function `check_lib':
C:\Users\eshirokov\Documents\shirokov\project\build-ARM-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug/../ARM/ARM/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.26-winx64/include/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h:77: undefined reference to `check(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
C:\Users\eshirokov\Documents\shirokov\project\build-ARM-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug/../ARM/ARM/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.26-winx64/include/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h:78: undefined reference to `check(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Ругается на вызов функций в файле driver.h (файл библиотеки mysqlcppconn):

```
inline static void check_lib()
{
  check(std::string{});
  check(std::map<std::string,std::string>{});
}
```

Объявление этих функций находится в этом же файле:

```
CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC void check(const std::string &);
CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC void check(const std::map<std::string,std::string> &);
```

Библиотека подключена правильно, потому что на другие функции не ругается.

Comment: Ну так бибилиотека vs14, а ваш проект ARM MinGW

Comment: ARM - это название проекта.

Comment: Судя по `build-ARM-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug`, вы собираете своё приложение с помощью MinGW. Скорее всего, библиотека была собрана с помощью MSVC, а они несовместимы между собой. На вашем месте я бы установил Visual Studio, а mysql connector взял из vcpkg